# Hot reload with ASP.NET Core and TailwindCSS (or: adding extra command to dotnet watch)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, msbuild

I'm investigating a good hot-reload workflow for using TailwindCSS with ASP.NET.

I've settled on using VSCode as VisualStudio doesn't have a good tailwind extension and Rider's extension doesn't support Razor files.

There are now two competing watchers that update files:

- `dotnet watch`, and
- `tailwindcss --watch`

Using them both at the same time almost works, but not quite: `dotnet watch` is faster and doesn't pick up the changes made by `tailwindcss --watch`. So you always see only the changes one time before the last time an edit was made.

I've tried adding the `tailwindcss` as a post-build step (it would be good enough enough if it triggeres on razor files):

```xml
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="npx tailwindcss -i ./wwwroot/css/input.css -o ./wwwroot/css/output.css" />
</Target>
```

However, that step doesn't get executed by `dotnet watch` when hot reload takes place.

`dotnet watch` does support running a command other than `run`, but still only those of the `dotnet` tool, and I don't see a way to execute arbitrary other commands.

Does anyone have more ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found your question and had the exact same use case. Managed to figure it out with a bit of fiddling.

So as you've got in your .csproj:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="npx tailwindcss -i ./wwwroot/css/input.css -o ./wwwroot/css/output.css" />
</Target>
```

But the next part that is missing is the hot-reload functionality.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-watch#hot-reload specifically this section 'lets you apply changes to a running app without having to **rebuild and restart it**'

So the above PostBuild step isn't being ran, and that's why there are no changes seen.

Running `dotnet watch --no-hot-reload` should instead cause the app to rebuild each time, while slightly slower, at least it automates the tailwind commands.

There is also this section in the dotnet watch docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-watch#advanced-configuration where I think it may be possible to trigger the command based on that ItemGroup, but I'm not a MSBuild expert and have no clue how you'd go about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way and it's a little hacky but hot reloading seems to keep working as intended.

Use your normal Tailwind CLI watcher e.g. `npx tailwindcss -i ./app.css -o ./wwwroot/app.css --watch`

Create the following static class and put it somewhere in your project:

```cs
[assembly: System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdateHandler(typeof(HotReloadDelayer))]

public static class HotReloadDelayer
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan DelayHotReload = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    
    public static void ClearCache(Type[]? updatedTypes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clearing cache...");
    }

    public static void UpdateApplication(Type[]? updatedTypes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Giving Tailwind {DelayHotReload.Seconds} seconds to settle...");
        Thread.Sleep(DelayHotReload);
        Console.WriteLine("Reloading...");
    }
}
```

(It looks like sorcery but it actually gets picked up by dotnet watch. You may rename the class as you like.)

This will make the hot reloader wait for 3 seconds before actually reloading the application code. Adjust `DelayHotReload` depending on how long it takes Tailwind to do its thing.